# Whenever I watch videos, my screen gets flashes of snow

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video, youtube

I'm using a 15 inch mid 2010 macbook with 10.8.4. It happens both on my cinema display and laptop display. It happens sporadically and had me questioning whether I was actually seeing it for a while. I notice mostly on youtube videos, but I think it's occurring from other sources as well.

Somebody could be playing a prank on me (as my buddies are likely to do), but nobody has confessed and I can't really find anything about the issue.

Any Ideas?

Comment: That is normal behavior!. -if you live on North pole :):)

Answer (score 1):

Depending what kind of flashes you have it is unknown, but there is one we can take care off.

Go to your system preference and click on Accessibility.

Check if the Flash the screen on error is enabled.

If yes, disable it.

[image]

Comment: This is a different kind of flash (using the test to demo it.) The one I'm experiencing is more like static in an older TV with poor signal, although lasting only for a flash.

Comment: OK :) do you have it only with online content (you do not have it when playing video that is saved on your computer, or is that not the case?

Comment: It is only streaming video.

Comment: Welcome back :) so you still have the problem! does it repeat with same video ?

Comment: It happens sporadically. I can't seem to get it to happen on the same spots in videos. I noticed it happening on a Netflix video earlier today, but trying the same video in the same spot it plays clear now.

Comment: How is your Internet connection doing ? Is it stable and fast ? Streaming Video requires lots of bandwidth (speed) so check it out.